# iptables with non_transparent squid proxy

Tags: linux, iptables, squid

iptables has been working well with squid transparent. but with squid authentication method, its has some problems.
due to documents i found that, because suid in authentication mode, is destiation for packets, cannot set rules with iptables for actual destination/source.

is this right? has any solution?

if dosnt right, can you give me some squid config file with AD integration SSo, or any other authentication method

excuse me for my bad english. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use authentication with a transparent proxy server. The browser needs to know it is communicating with a proxy server in order to provide credentials using the Proxy-Authenticate header.

If you wish to authenticate your clients, you will need to configure their browsers to use the proxy, not install it inline.